# data inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two class, one for storing base data, and the other for storing additional data as following:

```
struct AnimationState(){
    virtual ~ AnimationState(){};
    Vector3f m_spacialData;
    float m_fTimeStamp;
}
```

And the derived class:

```
struct HermiteAnimationState() : public AnimationState{
     virtual ~HermiteAnimationState(){};
     Vector3f m_tangentIn;
     Vector3f m_tangentOut;
}
```

**My question:** is how can I, at first, create an instance of **HermiteAnimationState**, and then upcast it to **AnimationState** for storing in a vector like this:

```
std::vector<AnimationState>     m_vStates;
...
```

Lately, I can get the object **AnimationState** and downcast it to **HermiteAnimationState** for accessing the additional data (member m_tangentIn and m_tangentOut).

```
HermiteAnimationState* p = dynamic_cast<HermiteAnimationState*>(&m_vStates[i])
```

Comment: You should use std::vector of smart pointers: std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AnimationState>> instead of storing objects by value

Comment: @AlexT: Thanks for your support. There's any other way which we don't need to use dynamic allocation?

Comment: The problem is that phisical size fo the base object is less then derived one so std::vector will slice HermiteAnimationState if you try forcefully (with cast) push it into std::vector<AnimationState>. This is in general bad practice. By the way std::vector will do dynamic allocation anyway... If you really want to avoid dynamic memory you should use built-in arrays on stack

Answer (score 1):

The way polymorphism works in C++ is that if `B` is a base class and `D` is derived from `B`, then:

- a pointer to `D` can be used where a pointer to `B` is expected
- a reference to `D` can be used where a reference to `B` is expected

What you *can't* do in C++ is actually use a *value* of type `D` in a context where a *value* of type `B` is expected. For example, you can't store derived objects in an array of base object. This makes sense when you consider that a derived object may have a different size from a base object.

Similarly, you can't store derived objects in a vector of base objects.

What you *can* do is store *pointers* to `HermiteAnimationState` in a vector of *pointers* to `AnimationState`. It's up to you how to manage the memory. For example, the following would be valid:

```
std::vector<AnimationState*> m_vStates;
HermiteAnimationState h_a_s;
m_vStates.push_back(&h_a_s);
```

...

```
HermiteAnimationState* p = dynamic_cast<HermiteAnimationState*>(m_vStates[i])
```

Since `h_a_s` is a local variable, it'll be destroyed automatically at the end of its scope.

But this is *probably* an unworkable approach, because you probably want the objects referred to by the vector elements to persist beyond the current scope. We can use `std::unique_ptr` for this purpose. A `std::unique_ptr` *owns* the object it points to, and as long as it stays alive, so does that object; and it deletes the object when it is itself destroyed. So a vector of `std::unique_ptr` objects behaves like a vector of objects themselves in terms of memory management. Now you can do

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AnimationState*>> m_vStates;
m_vStates.emplace_back(new HermiteAnimationState);
```

...

```
HermiteAnimationState* p =
  dynamic_cast<HermiteAnimationState*>(m_vStates[i].get());
```

(Note, however, that you can't copy this vector; you can only move it.)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to use some kind of reference to the pointed object because you need dynamic polymorphism.

The simplest but error-prone would be using "naked" pointers. The first thing that is problematic with this is that you have to do the destroying manually: containers will destroy the pointer, not what is pointed.

The safer way to do this is to use smart pointers, which are designed to do the destruction depending on a pre-fixed rule that the smart pointer embedd in it's type. The simplest one and certainly the best choice if you are doubting is std::unique_ptr, which can't be copied but can be moved. The other choice, which should be thought carefully about before being used, is the std::shared_ptr which is useful IFF you don't know when you should destroy these objects but you know it's when some systems will refer no more to it. Some other systems might just be observing that object, in which case std::weak_ptr.

---

Now, from reading your question, I think you are certainly processing a lot of these animation data. There is an obvious design issue there, I think, I might be wrong.
However, it looks like, if you have a lot of these AnimationState to manage, in a loop, you will get performance issues. This is common issues in games, mainly caused by "cache conherency".

What I would recommand in this case, would be to NOT use

- inheritance: it's an invitation to the cpu to jump all over the place and trigger cache misses;
- dynamic_cast: it's one of the few operations that are not guaranteed to end in a predictable time (with new and delete for example), which basically mean that if you are in a critical loop, you can lose a lot of time through it. In some cases, you can't avoid using dynamic cast (like when doing dynamic plugins), but in most cases, using it just because you have chosen to use inheritance is just wrong. If you use inheritance, then you should use virtual calls.

However, what I suggest is even more drastic: don't use inheritance at all.

Obviously, this is only an advice. If you are not doing something with a critical loop, it doesn't matter. I'm just worried because it looks like you are doing some inheritance for composition, which always have bad consequences both on readability of the code and performance.

Comment: Thanks so much for your thoughtful support. This is as exact as you say that I have a critical loop for processing AnimationStates.  For every bone, I make a loop over all of its AnimationStates (100 bones, and each bone has about 200 states, and this is called every frame) But if data inheritance is not advisable in this case, could you suggest me any other pattern for resolving this problem. I need a base AnimationState class for storing basic data, and a derived HermiteAnimationState for storing TagentIn and TangentOut of each state.

Comment: There are several ways but they all depend on your specific case. One way would be to have each different type in different containers, but as values, so that there is arrays of small objects. Look for "data oriented design". Another way, maybe simpler, would be to have all the data from all kind of animations into one type. However, having small types helps a lot with efficiency too, so look for data oriented techniques used in game engines and you should find several ways we use to fix these problems.